# Python real-time create image from input, python3

Tags: image, python-3.x, real-time

Every approximately second(sometime twice a second) I have a data from COM-port, like: [1 2 3 1].

This list mean a part of image - first vertical line.

I want draw in real-time whole image, like scanner.

for example:

```
First data coming:
x
x
x 
x

Second
x x
x x
x x
x x
..
After N - data tacking:
x x x ... x
x x x ... x
x x x ... x
x x x ... x
```

How can I do that?

I think, I need to accamulate array, like:

```
Array=list()
new_data=..
Array.append(new_data)
*Create_image*
```

Comment: Do you want draw image with coloured pixel or with just numbers?

Comment: Try Pillow's ImageDraw module: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/ImageDraw.html

Comment: number means brightness of pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED] Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
cans=Canvas(root,height=500,width=600)
cans.pack()
delay = 1  # milliseconds
array_list=[] # this will be list of arrays

def get_new_data():
    new_data=[]
    new_data = #whatever write code here how you get next new list from somewhere
    array_list.append(raw_data)    
    return array_list

def get_lits(x):
    get_new_data()
    return array_list[x-2]

def get_color(y, x):
    max_num = 15
    raw_array=get_data(x)
    c = raw_array[y] * 255 / max_num
    colorname = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (c, c, c)
    return colorname

def draw_line(i=2, j=0):
    if i <= 600:
        if j<=500:
            cans.create_line(i,j,i+1,j, fill=get_color(j, i))
            root.after(delay, draw_line, i+0, j+1)
        elif j>150:
            j=0
            root.after(delay, draw_line, i+1)
draw_line()       
root.mainloop()
```

Just write your code how to get new array in `get_new_data()`, also change `max_num =12` to your maximum value of array.

[image: 1]

Comment: exactly!
I get data like this:
while true:
    data_raw = ser.readline()
where data_raw is value of pixel of "vertical line".
How can I modify you code?

Comment: Please, write clearly your data_raw value or type. Did you mean that value of pixels is RGB color code or coordinates? And why lines?

Comment: For example I have output [10,12,3,4...].
which means the value of pixels in vertical line.

I received this arrays many times per second and I need to synchronized process of drawing.

Comment: I explain again: Pixel has a color and coordinates. In your example, you should explain value of arrays is exactly what it is. And vertical line only has starting point(coordiantes), ending point and color. If you want to draw, you should use either pixels or lines.

Comment: Value is brightness of pixel in gray-scale.
Vertical line define by number of package.
If we received first time, this line is for x=1.
second time - x=2.

Comment: OK, got it. how much is the biggest value of output array? I mean Min=0 and Max=?

Comment: size of output array is about 250 digits. the value from 0 to 65535.

Comment: And number of package? If value vlactuates from 0 to 65535, it is almost impossible to convert them to grayscale.

Comment: they come in series all time, each package of 1024 -> x = 0, 1025 -> x=1,.. 2048-> x=0, and so on.

Comment: Well, try to change my code. If you fail, search from google. If you prefer, accept my answer.